# How to get vector with amplitudes?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiokit

I tried with AVFoundation, AudioKit and EZAudio. But I could not.
I want some way to get all the amplitudes of the whole song (without play the music), to have the average amplitude. Does anyone know how?
I do not need the whole algorithm. Examples and a way forward are welcome.

```
do {
   let file = try AKAudioFile(forReading: URL.init(string: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TFB9", ofType: "mp3")!)!)
   self.analyzedPlayer = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
   self.player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
}
catch {
   print(error)
}

let equalizerFilter = AKEqualizerFilter(analyzedPlayer, centerFrequency: 9000, bandwidth: 1000, gain: 9)
let lowPassFilter = AKLowPassFilter.init(equalizerFilter, cutoffFrequency: 10000, resonance: 0)
hightPassFilter = AKHighPassFilter.init(lowPassFilter, cutoffFrequency: 8000, resonance: 0)

AKAmplitudeTracker.init(hightPassFilter, threshold: 0.42, thresholdCallback: {_ in
   self.delegate?.signal()
})
```

Comment: Show the community what you have done so far.

Comment: AVFoundation, AudioKit and EZAudio all can read a file.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I was able to read the amplitude while the music played.

Comment: I think this question is too broad, it's likely why it has been down-voted.  You would be better served to continue researching what is already out there.  You will find examples.

Comment: That is the problem. I found no examples. I'm a week into this and nothing, just have real-time examples.